# Android - PhoneGap application (keystore file error)

Tags: android, cordova, android-keystore, phonegap-build

I am developing a PhoneGap application through Eclipse on the Android platform. My code is ready and run perfectly.

Now, I already created a signed [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file in release mode. So, when I uploaded this keystore file on "**build.phonegap.com**", and clicked on <kbd>Submit key</kbd>, I got an error like this:

> Error: extension did not match expected (keystore)"

I don't know what is going wrong in this. Is there a proper solution?

Answer (score 5):

A command-line solution:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore yourappname.keystore -alias appnamealias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

According to: [This Post](http://sikitech.blogspot.com/2013/02/howto-solve-error-extension-did-not.html)

Comment: Hey, i got an error while generating this keystore file. Error: "Keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test.keystore (Access is denied)" Please help me fast...

Comment: Try to run the cmd prompt as administrator

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating your keystore file in Eclipse make sure to manually set the file extension to ".keystore" - instead of the default file name with no extension.

Answer (score 2):

What tools do we need to develop an Android keystore file?

1. The Android keystore file can be created in the Java Development Kit (JDK), and to download the installation file, click on this link: [Install JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
2. How do we create the Android keystore file?

   Standard procedure: First you need to **open the command prompt as administrator**

   To go from a directory to its parent directory, write **cd..** (push the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button). Keep doing it until you reach **c:>**.

   When you are at **c:/**, write **cd Program files** (push the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button).

   `cd Java` (push the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button).

   `cd jdk1.7.0_03` (push the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button).

   **`cd bin` (push the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button).**

   **`keytool -genkey -v -keystore Your_personal_file_title.keystore -alias Your_personal_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**` (push the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button).

   **Remember to edit the two text file `Your_personal_file_title` and `Your_personal_alias`.**

   And enter your profile information.

   Afterwards it will create your Android keystore file in your C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin directory, with the name you gave it…
3. You now have your keystore file and can activate it in whatever application you generate your Android apps in (for example, build.phonegap.com).

Please remember to use CMD as ***administrator***.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own .keystore file. To do this:

- Open CMD
- Type:

  ```
  cd C:\java path\java\jdk7\bin
  keytool -genkey -v -keystore yourappname.keystore -alias appnamealias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
  ```

After that you will have a new release keystore.

Comment: but i want to create keystore from Eclipse only And when i am doing that from eclipse it shows me the above error while i build my phonegap app on build.phonegap.com. So, please suggest me.